# Does $P(X^m \in B) \rightarrow P(X \in B)$ for boxes $B$ imply $X^m \xrightarrow[]{d} X$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I was trying to solve a problem and wanted to employ the following, thinking it was true because its true for $1$ dimension, but cannot find a reference!

If $\{X^m\}_m$ and $X$ are random variables on $\mathbb{R}$, [the Portmanteau Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) states $X^m \xrightarrow[]{d} X$ is equivalent to $P(X^m \in A) \rightarrow P(X \in A)$ for all continuity sets $A$, where a continuity set is any Borel measurable set whose topological boundary has probability $0$.

The definition of convergence in distribution for $\mathbb{R}$ is $P(X^m \leq t) \rightarrow P(X \leq t)$ for all $t$ at which $P(X \leq t)$ is continuous. Notice this implies $(-\infty, t]$ is a continuity set.

In other words, proving convergence on continuity sets of the form $(-\infty, t]$ implies convergence on any continuity set. Does this generalize to higher dimensions? A box in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is any product of $n$ closed or open intervals.

$\textbf{Question}$: If $\{X^m\}_m, X$ are random variables on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $P(X^m \in B) \rightarrow P(X \in B)$ for all boxes $B$ with $P(X \in \partial B) =0 $, does $P(X^m \in A) \rightarrow P(X \in A)$ for all other continuity sets $A$?

Comment: Convergence  of Probability Measures by Billingsley has Portmanteau's Theorem for random elements in a metric space.

Comment: Does this prove what I asked? I have found versions of Portmanteau's lemma in higher dimensions, but none of them proved what I was wondering.

Comment: I think your result is part of the proof of Theorem 29.1 in Probability and Measures by Billingsley.

Comment: I read the proof and do not understand it well enough to conclude if it implies my result or not.

Comment: @geetha290krm This is a minor gripe, but "Portmanteau" is descriptive, not a name, so it's "the Portmanteau theorem/lemma" rather than "Portmanteau's theorem".  (Similar to "the Mean Value theorem")

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the information.

Comment: Even in the one dimensional case, one typically uses Skorokhod's Representation Theorem as convergence of the cdf at continuity points, allows you to conisder generalized inverse cdf on $([0,1],\lambda,\mathcal{B})$ which will have same distribution as the variates and will converge almost surely. Then you can use that for an open set $G$, and $X_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}X$, you have $\lim\inf\mathbf{1}_{G}(X_{n})\geq \mathbf{1}_{G}(X)$ and use Fatou's Lemma to conclude $\lim\inf P(X_{n}\in G)\geq P(X\in G)$. This allows you to conclude for all continuity sets.

Comment: To be entirely truthful, I have never honestly read a proof of Skorokhod's Theorem in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$. You can see the proof of Theorem 29.3 in Billingsley's book and the remark above it in which he states that the proof for $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ is harder. Basically, what you explicitly need to go from boxes to arbitrary continuity sets is the theorem that convergence of joint cdf implies weak convergence. It is this particular theorem which will require Skorokhod's Representation (or the proof of it like I said in my previous comment). But the result (that you want) is true.